# Redirect When Using JSON On PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, redirect

I have a ajax form that goes to a php file, i dont want users to be able to directly enter the php file into the URL bar so how would i be able to redirect them if they enter that php file, i cant simply add a `header("location:index.html")` or the form wouldnt work.

```
<?php
$Reg['E'] = 'Test';

echo json_encode($Reg);
?>
```

Comment: Technically, if your AJAX can reach it then there will always be a way to reach it

Comment: is there any other way i could do this? or should i just have my php in the same page as the ajax form? would that even work?

Comment: There is no way to do this. Whatever you do, people will be able to see it and do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to be 100% certain because there's nothing technically special about an ajax request vs. any other request.  If you're using jQuery, you can do a check on the `X-Requested-With` header:

```
if (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' )
```

...otherwise redirect.  You can also put a token in the form such as a random `md5` hash and check whether that token is submitted along with the request (compared to a value stored session).  This at least requires that the form page be visited first to generate the token, and "normal" users will not be able to get the token.

Comment: the token thing you suggested Worked! you have been answering a lot of  my questions lately, thanks!